# Oc get pods - Command to just print pod names

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubectl

I want to get a list of just the pod names and the Result should not include the status, number of instances etc.

I am using the command

`oc get pods`

It prints

```
Pod1-qawer            Running           1/1           2d
Pod2g-bvch            Running           1/1           3h
```

Expected result

```
Pod1-qawer
Pod2g-bvch
```

How do i avoid the extra details from getting printed

Comment: Have you tried `oc get pods -o name`? Run `oc get --help` for help strings on all the options.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But it adds a pod/ prefix before the pod names. Is there a way to suppress that too?

Comment: Use `oc get pod -o template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'`. See https://cookbook.openshift.org/working-with-resource-objects/how-can-i-selectively-display-attributes-of-a-resource.html

Answer (score 23):

You can omit the headers with `--no-headers` and you can use `-o custom-columns=` to customize the output.

```
oc get pods -o custom-columns=POD:.metadata.name --no-headers
```

Example output

```
$ oc get pods -o custom-columns=POD:.metadata.name --no-headers
goapp-75d9b6bfbf-b5fdh
httpd-58c5c54fff-b97h8
app-proxy-6c8dfb4899-8vdkb
app-64d5985fdb-xjp58
httpd-dd5976fc-rsnhz
```

Comment: In my case I needed the name of running pods and it had to be filtered by a label. To see the available labels: `--show-labels=true`. Filter for label: `-l label=value`. Only running pods: `--show-all=false`

Comment: hi i've accidentialy downvoted your answer ... Can you make a edit so that I can upvote it

Answer (score 7):

Use the `oc get <object> -o name` syntax, here (for pods):

`oc get pods -o name`

but it also applies to dc, svc, route, template, ..

Sample output:

```
pod/m0001-v5-tst-1-b5xfs
pod/m0001-v5-tst-1-mv5zl
```

note that these object prefixes (here: `pod/`) are perfectly acceptable for all oc client tools commands, so no need to strip the prefixes, they can stay and be processed further, e.g. thus:

```
$ oc describe $(oc get pods -o name | grep m0001-v5) | grep TAG`

      CONTAINER_TAG:               20200430
      CONTAINER_TAG:               20200430
```

Notice we do not use `pods` as usual (i.e. `oc describe` not `oc describe pods`) to avoid duplication.

Another example:

```
$ oc delete $(oc get dc,svc,route,is -o name)
service "nginx" deleted
route.route.openshift.io "nginx" deleted
imagestream.image.openshift.io "nginx" deleted
```

Comment: it works for almost all oc client tools - except for the copy command

Answer (score 0):

`oc get po --no-headers | awk '{print $1}'`

Answer (score 0):

try:

oc get pods |awk -F" " 'print {$0}'